# Firebase nested value

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query items in my firebase database based on an attribute value.

Here is my structure:

[image]

Here is my POJO object:

```
public class LapTime {

    private int vehicleType;
    private String track;
    private String user;
    private int time;
}
```

And here is my query code:

```
mDatabase.child("lap-time").orderByChild("track").equalTo(mTrackUuid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            time = dataSnapshot.getValue(LapTime.class).getTime() + "ms");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

My problem is that the datasnapshot I get back has for root `lap-time` and not the UUID, thus the `getValue(LapTime.class)` give me an empty object...

Here is the datasnapshot I get:

```
DataSnapshot { key = lap-time, value = {-KXwSxD0GYVC6awV8abw={track=-KXwSxCeV2Ib4Gt4pvjy, time=105000, vehicle-type=0, user=ZQKwPfRF0mVL5jAO7FaSPcsF7t42}} }
```

And this is what I would like to get:

```
DataSnapshot { key = -KXwSxD0GYVC6awV8abw, value ={track=-KXwSxCeV2Ib4Gt4pvjy, time=105000, vehicle-type=0, user=ZQKwPfRF0mVL5jAO7FaSPcsF7t42}} }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: may be similar issue to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928787/cannot-retrieve-a-list-into-firebase-database/40929176?noredirect=1#comment69070082_40929176

Comment: Do you want to parse all the children of lap-time or a specific one? You can iterate through the children with `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`. Otherwise, you need to set the `ValueEventListener` on the node with the UID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your query code can actually have more than one result you should be calling `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` and iterating through the children to get the result you're looking for. Particularly, `mDatabase.child("lap-time").orderByChild("track").equalTo(mTrackUuid)` is a query that could have multiple results since there could be a situation where multiple `LapTime` objects could have a track that points to the same `mTrackUuid`. Now, to get the result of the log you posted you need to construct a the query like so: `mDatabase.child("lap-time").child("-KXwSxD0GYVC6awV8abw")`. Notice how the `orderByChild/equalTo` queries are gone since those result in a conditional query that may return a list of data instead of a singular value.

Comment: How would I do if I don't know the UID `-KXwSxD0GYVC6awV8abw`? These are generated automatically and I don't keep track of them.

Comment: Ok got it to work by iterating through the children!